# Enabling File-Based Encryption/Direct Boot Android 9 OP3T

Tags: encryption, 9.0-pie

I am trying to figure out how to enable file-based encryption on my OnePlus 3T with Android 9 Pie. The developer options from Android 7 Nougat are not present on my phone.

I have a custom ROM (Pixel Experience) installed.

I understand that I will have to wipe my data.

How do I enable the file-based encryption method/Direct Boot?